# How to evaluate the overall safety of a web offering?

Tags: web-application

Background: I have been trying to find a simple app to document my children's milestones in life.

I have been signing up for a couple of free services and trying to evaluate their offerings. I evaluate ease of use, speed, potential cost, etc... but during this process I started to wonder which one of these services are actually 'safe' . And by safe I mean my account information (like password) and children's data (pictures, videos, etc..) are stored somewhere completely unknown.

So I tried to trace the origin of some of these applications, but it seems harder than I thought. Most of the apps do not have any information on where they are based out of (country). I really got suspicious when I started seeing language choices for some of the sites (some I can't even recognize) I was also suspicious when I noticed that some of these offerings 'look similar' (theme, etc...).

So to circle back. What factors can one use when evaluating safety of web offerings? Is there an easy way to trace an application back to a trusted company? Is the safest thing to do is to use a well-known, established site, like Facebook or Google+ even though their features for a particular need is limited?

Answer (score 3):

> What factors can one use when evaluating safety of web offerings? Is there an easy way to trace an application back to a trusted company?

This is an opinion-based question, but I still apologise for giving a very non-objective answer.

How would you answer your own question for a different service altogether - say, a house renovation firm, or a car? Most of the issues would not be too different.

I can think of some parameters, most of which are off topics on SE:

- **brand strength**: quantity has a quality all of its own. And large firms and established brands have more budget and much more to lose if they screw up. So by and large, you want someone that's too big to fail you. Yes, it's true that to a big firm, a lone, even mightily pissed customer is a negligible nuisance that will be ignored - but the truth is, as an individual you would be a minor nuisance to everybody except very, very small start-ups. Demoting yourself from "minor" to "negligible" purchases the advantage of a larger entity that won't ignore larger issues.
- **brand "sincerity"**: a service calling itself "Googgle" or "Googlle" is likely up to no good, or at the very least has serious marketing issues. Which probably translates in a too-cavalier attitude towards mostly everything, including security and privacy. Thus, I agree that the similarities you lament between different services are to be considered suspicious (or may indicate a large use of standard free tools to develop a web site, which may in turn indicate a small-scale operation thrown together "to see how it goes").
- **reputation among customers**: this is relatively easy in real life, especially in a small town where everybody knows everybody else. That's the key - *knowing*. On the Internet you need to surf to find people's opinions of something. I usually employ the following rule of thumb:

  - *no* opinions: this service or product is mostly unknown. Handle with care.
  - lots of bad opinions, few good opinions: probably a bad choice, even if I'll want to read several of those opinions to understand the timeframe/version/context they're referring to. In your case you might have lots of people fuming furious, and vocally so, at not being able to upload selfies from FooPhone 1.2x, or some other feature you don't value a whit. Those opinions you would discard.
  - some good opinions, no bad opinions whatsoever: I'd be somewhat suspicious. Several firms and services have been known to try, and succeed, in removing bad reviews - instead of the reasons thereof.
  - good opinions with similar wording, grammar constructs (and errors), or structure: another very bad sign of someone who bought good reviews wholesale. If overwhelmed by "normal" good opinions, it could be an error in judgment, long since amended. If most good opinions are [astroturfed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astroturfing), keep the hell away.
- **product/service quality**: this, only you can evaluate.

  - other similar services/products out there?
  - what differences? Are they important?
- **technical telltales**:

  - is the site [properly protected](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html)?
  - does it employ some kind of [third-party review](http://www.trust-guard.com/McAfee-Secure-s/53.htm)?
  - if you register and e.g. fake losing your password, what do you get?

    - an email with your old password in the clear: I'd take [Gandalf's advice](http://www.quickmeme.com/img/06/0686c975290c0436cdf73611d9252cefd066f1701c40b32af8b2958371b61976.jpg).
    - an email with a "reset your pass" link valid for a few hours only: *good*.
    - if you *also* fake losing the email (e.g. you revoked the email service and forgot it was linked to the site), does pressing the case with the service support solve the problem? If yes: **BAD** sign. If they require proof of identity through secure means: good. If they don't attempt a solution: middling-bad case.
- **other information**

  - the contact page, when available, can tell something about the firm's whereabouts.
  - domain tools such as WHOIS and DNS lookups can tell you the owner of the domain, the location of the web server(s), the location of the web server(s); then you can investigate *other* customers of the same domain service and server hosting. Anonymous or "protected" domains aren't very conducive to trust, and low-cost, "no question asked" servers, maybe hosted in rogue States, are obviously a very bad sign.
  - the same tools can tell you when a domain was first established.
  - tools such as the Web Archive and the Wayback Machine can probably be used to see how the domain evolved; whether it moved from selling used cars to selling dental surgery advice; all of which is valuable information.

Comment: Thank you, this has some good measures I can look for that I have not thought about before.